# How to correctly format JSON when sending between two Lambdas?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send JSON data from one parent lambda to multiple child lambdas. I am sending the data as JSON, it prints in the sending lambda with double quotes. However, the receiving lambda receives it only with single quotes:

```
event: [{'account': 'greg', 'caption': 'test test'}]
```

This is causing the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

I have tried using `.encode()` and `base64.b64encode()` but cannot get the correct format. What am I doing wrong? How do you send correctly formatted JSON between lambdas?

**Sending Lambda:**

```
response = client.invoke(
     FunctionName = 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxx:function:xxx',
     InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
     Payload = json.dumps(sendData),
)
```

**Receiving Lambda**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     print("event: " + str(event))
     handle_data(str(event))

     return {

            'statusCode': '200',

            'body': 'Saved'

     }

def handle_data(data):
     data = json.loads(data)
     print(data)

     write_to_dynamo(data)

     return print("Done")
```

Comment: Which line of code results in JSONDecodeError? Be aware that when Python prints a dict, it prints string keys/values with single quotes and when you stringify a dict and print that, the same thing happens. The `event` parameter here is presumably a dict.

Comment: The "json.loads(data)" throws the error.

Comment: You don't show any code that calls json.loads.

Comment: Didn't think it was needed but I have updated it now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you stringifying (or attempting to dump to JSON) the event dict in the first place? Why not simply pass it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are sending the data to your `handle_data` method.  The `event` that you get in the lambda handler is already a list, you don't need to do a `json.loads` on it.  What you are currently doing is converting the python list to a string and then trying to decode it as json (which won't work).  Just send the data to your internal handler as is and don't try to do a json.loads on it (the aws api already does that conversion for you automatically)

Receiving Lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     handle_data(event)

     return {

            'statusCode': '200',

            'body': 'Saved'

     }

def handle_data(data):
     print(data)

     write_to_dynamo(data)

     return print("Done")
```

Relevant snippet from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html):

> When Lambda invokes your function handler, the Lambda runtime passes two arguments to the function handler:

> The first argument is the event object. An event is a JSON-formatted document that contains data for a Lambda function to process. The Lambda runtime converts the event to an object and passes it to your function code. It is usually of the Python dict type. It can also be list, str, int, float, or the NoneType type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't sending JSON. A JSON document is a string. Use `json.dumps(e)` and send the result, this will encode it as valid JSON rather than using python's built in output formatting.